# Add multiple OIDC authentication options in FastAPI

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi, openid-connect

I've added Google's OIDC authentication to my FastAPI application.

```
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi.security import OpenIdConnect

oidc_google = OpenIdConnect(openIdConnectUrl='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration')

@app.get('/foo')
def bar(token: Depends(oidc_google)):
    return "You're Authenticated"
```

Now I want to give the user the option to login with another OIDC provider (e.g: Microsoft). Something like this:

```
oidc_google = OpenIdConnect(openIdConnectUrl='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration')
oidc_microsoft = OpenIdConnect(openIdConnectUrl='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration')

@app.get('/foo')
def bar(token: Depends(oidc_google or oidc_microsoft)):
    return "You're Authenticated"
```

Also seems like you can only set one configuration for oidc in swagger UI:

```
app = FastAPI(
    swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url='/api/v1/oidc/callback',
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'clientId': settings.OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
        'clientSecret': settings.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
)
```

Which makes it even more complicated. I couldn't find a working solution so far.
Is there a working solution to add multiple OIDC options for authentication in FastAPI?

Comment: did you try raising an issue on Github?

Comment: @Benni As I remember there is already an issue about it. btw I've solved the issue with a work around, I just didn't have time to add the working solution here